# Any way to add to value in MYSQL database without querying it first?

Tags: php, mysql

is there any way to safely update a value in a mysql table without querying it first, for example, if i have a number stored such as 5, and i want to add 1 to it every time an action is performed, is there anyway i can add to that without performing an actual query to get the value of it first?

Comment: to insert data , why u need to query? more info please!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
mysql_query("UPDATE `table` SET `col`=`col`+1 WHERE condition=met")
```

That will increment the column value.

Answer (score 2):

You can try by adding a trigger. A trigger is fired automatically whenever a INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE  happens.

More on triggers: http://www.sqlteam.com/article/an-introduction-to-triggers-part-i

In this case you can use something like:

```
CREATE TRIGGER Increment_By_one
ON table_name
FOR INSERT
AS
'your incrementation sql string goes here...
```